# firewalld SSH closed ports still logging failed login attempts

Tags: ssh, firewalld

Setting up a new VPS with almalinux.

I've set up firewalld with the following settings

```
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https
  ports: 80/tcp 443/tcp 7822/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Why is there still failed log in attempts logged in /var/log/secure when the ports they are connecting to are closed?

```
Apr 15 14:11:57 server sshd[46737]: Failed password for root from 148.113.133.177 port 43582 ssh2
Apr 15 14:11:57 server sshd[46737]: Received disconnect from 148.113.133.177 port 43582:11: Bye Bye [preauth]

Apr 15 14:12:15 server sshd[46743]: Invalid user chenyoumin from 27.254.149.199 port 60384
Apr 15 14:12:15 server sshd[46743]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 15 14:12:15 server sshd[46743]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=27.254.149.199
```

When i try to ssh in to the server with a random port:
`ssh -p 50645 root@server.com`

it returns:
`ssh: connect to host server.com port 50645: No route to host`

And nothing is logged in /var/log/secure.

---

**Update**

I've disabled firewalld and enabled nftables. I've loading in the following rule set

```
table inet firewall {
        chain inbound_ipv4 {
        }

        chain inbound_ipv6 {
                icmpv6 type { nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
        }

        chain inbound {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state vmap { invalid : drop, established : accept, related : accept }
                iifname "lo" accept
                meta protocol vmap { ip : jump inbound_ipv4, ip6 : jump inbound_ipv6 }
                tcp dport { 80, 443, 7822 } accept
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        }
}
table inet f2b-table {
        set addr-set-sshd {
                type ipv4_addr
                elements = { 45.89.110.110 }
        }

        chain f2b-chain {
                type filter hook input priority filter - 1; policy accept;
                meta l4proto { tcp } ip saddr @addr-set-sshd reject
        }
}
```

Now this seems to work fine. any attempt to ssh to a port other than 7822 just hangs, and there are no entries in the logs.

But I am still seeing brute force attempts from bots in the logs. How are they doing this and how do I stop it? Do they somehow have these connections open before the rules were applied? How can I drop these connections without restarting the VPS?

```
Apr 16 14:30:39 server sshd[61577]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 16 14:30:39 server sshd[61577]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=103.39.133.250
Apr 16 14:30:41 server sshd[61577]: Failed password for invalid user user from 103.39.133.250 port 48096 ssh2
Apr 16 14:30:46 server sshd[61580]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=43.156.239.10  user=root
Apr 16 14:30:49 server sshd[61580]: Failed password for root from 43.156.239.10 port 40702 ssh2
Apr 16 14:30:58 server sshd[61583]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=165.22.96.129  user=root
Apr 16 14:31:00 server sshd[61583]: Failed password for root from 165.22.96.129 port 49100 ssh2
Apr 16 14:31:14 server sshd[61586]: Invalid user user from 43.156.82.82 port 36394
Apr 16 14:31:14 server sshd[61586]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 16 14:31:14 server sshd[61586]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=43.156.82.82
Apr 16 14:31:16 server sshd[61586]: Failed password for invalid user user from 43.156.82.82 port 36394 ssh2
Apr 16 14:31:18 server sshd[61589]: Invalid user ubuntu from 213.190.4.134 port 36238
Apr 16 14:31:18 server sshd[61589]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 16 14:31:18 server sshd[61589]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=213.190.4.134
Apr 16 14:31:20 server sshd[61589]: Failed password for invalid user ubuntu from 213.190.4.134 port 36238 ssh2
```

Comment: Please add output of `iptables-save` to the question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I added it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your firewalld policy applied in the iptables-save output.

Your INPUT change has default policy of accept. And it only jumps to f2b-SSH chain which I suspect is managed by fail2ban and bans a lot of source hosts (which I suspect are banging at your sshd server).

If the address has not been banned by fail2ban it will finally get accepted and this is why you see messages in logs.

Have you started firewalld? Did it start properly?

BTW, which AlmaLinux is it? 8 is still on iptables, 9 is on nftables AFAIR. If this is AlmaLinux 9, provide `nft list ruleset` output.

Comment: It's Alma 8.7. But in firewalld.conf it says it's using ```FirewallBackend=nftables```. Why are the bans going to iptables if f2b is using firewalld-cmd for banactions? Also, my IP is not banned and the server returns ```No route to host``` on random ports with no logging. I'll add the ```nft list ruleset``` ouput now.

Comment: Apparently they've learned that your sshd is on port 7822 (or 80, or 443). Try to move it.

Comment: You are right. I un banned all IPs and changed the port and haven't had a hit in 30 minutes. Thank you very much. Now to figure out how to block port scans with nft. I found this https://superuser.com/a/1756860 but my kernel version is 4.18.0